Time-temperature relation in matter dominated and dark energy dominated era
Can we derive a cosmological relation between time and temperature in matter dominated era and in dark energy era? Something like the radiation era expression here
$$T= \frac{t^{-1/2} 1.15}{k_B}$$
taken from this question:
Is this formula for the time-temperature relation in this universe correct, or is there a more appropriate one?
Maybe it's a ridiculus question, but i would appreciate an answer.
I put a pic with an alternative form for the relation taken from a 1993 thesis

credits: COSMOLOGICAL PHASE TRANSITIONS by Janne Ignatius, Department of Theoretical Physics\Faculty of Science\University of Helsinki\Helsinki,Finland
1993

It isn’t clear what the units for that equation are supposed to be. In SI units it’s dimensionally inconsistent.

i took it for a previous question, in a paper by hogan 1983 you can find this version https://scihub.se/https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0370269383905531
Check eq 9 my friend
if my sci-hub link does not open, this is the paper https://inspirehep.net/literature/201169

Sorry, neither link goes to the paper. If the paper gives a formula that makes dimensional sense, then you should edit your question to use that version of the formula. I can’t see how the one you have makes any sense, other than saying $T$ is proportional to $t^{-1/2}$.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0370269383905531
eq 9

The article is paywalled. I’m not going to purchase the article to read eq. 9.

hahaahahh put in sci-hub and it opens, this is the reason i gave it to you in sci hub at first, bu it does not open the link here, take the link and put it in sci hub and it will open

Sorry, I’m not going to use a site that infringes copyrights. Bye.

ok thanks mate, everybody in academic society uses it, it was made by a good scientist girl. Alexandra Asanovna Elbakyan ,born 6 November 1988 is a Kazakhstani computer programmer and creator of the website Sci-Hub, which provides free access to research papers without regard for copyright.According to a study published in 2018, Sci-Hub provides access to nearly all scholarly literature.
Elbakyan has been described as "Science's Pirate Queen".In 2016, Nature included her in their list of the top ten "people who mattered" in science.Since 2011,she has been living in Russia.
Come on mate DO IT

Your comment was plagiarized without attribution from Wikipedia. Bye again.

Man you can have free access from your institute, why are you tryharding so much? I feel like I am talking to a kid dressed like Sheldon cooper

Why would you assume I have an institute? I’ve been retired for years and left physics decades ago after a postdoc in cosmology. Some people like stealing intellectual property and some people don’t… deal with it. I couldn’t care less what you do. Try reciprocating and cut out the insults. We have a Be Nice policy here.

Ok Choster sorry, I am going to be nice, I edited my question and I posted a picture from a thesis with the relation T~t^-1/2, also I gave credits to the source of the photo, to be right to you and the writer of the thesis. Can you help now?
